# Javascript when Customizer preview is ready/refreshed?

Tags: jquery, theme-customizer

I am trying to create a javascript which fires everytime the preview iframe is refreshed. I have found this one:

```
wp.customize.bind('ready', function () {

});
```

But this only works when the Customizer is first loaded. I use `transport` `postMessage` on my custom settings, and this only refreshes the iframe. How do I hook into this to know when the iframe has been refreshed?

Thank you!

Comment: wp.customize.previewer.bind( 'refresh', function() {
    wp.customize.previewer.refresh();
} );

Comment: please check link : https://make.xwp.co/2015/12/08/implementing-selective-refresh-in-the-customizer/

Comment: @vikrantzilpe I already use postMessage and selective refresh, that part works great. But I have a jQuery function that fires when an input is selected in the Customizer. Problem is that after I have entered something to the input and the content is selectivly refreshed it will not rerun this jQuery function.